# Consume API into aspnet core 2.2

Tags: api, asp.net-core

I have a web API which returns about 1000 records into json. Now I want to get all those records from json response and deserialize into a model

The code i have written so far is like following:

```
        public async Task<IActionResult>  GetList()
    {
        Facility facilityInfo = new Facility();
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("http://localhost:55555/api/Facilities"))
            {
                string apiResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                facilityInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Facility>(apiResponse);
            }
        }
     //-----------other parts of code-----------------
        return View();
    }
```

The **problem** is that it returns null **facilityInfo**

Thank you

Comment: What value is apiResponse ?

Comment: It is getting the value from json data

Comment: so is it valid json ?

Comment: It is like following:
{"items":[{"FacilityId":2986,"DistrictCode":"1304","FacilityName":"Kelagai Prison Health Clinic"}]}

Comment: Please update your question stating what the value of apiResponse is.

Comment: Could you please share your model and your request api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're deserializing something that has a property called items which is a list of Facilities. So if you have the following structure:

```
public class Facilities
{
    public List<Facility> items;
}
```

And then

```
Facilities facilities = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Facilities>(apiResponse);
```

The facilities.items property will contain the data.